# Is a question about configuring a server admin panel off topic?

Tags: discussion, moderation, off-topic

A three year old [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/277036/where-is-the-webmin-port-number-stored?noredirect=1#comment802935_277036)  of mine was just put "on hold" for relating to "[working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)."

The wording here is a little ambiguous. I understand why end use of panel software would be out of scope. However, configuring these panels does require sysadmin knowledge, and would otherwise be in scope.

I was surprised that an individual non moderator could place a question on hold that has been answered for over three years.What's the process for disputing that status?

Answer (score 9):

> The wording here is a little ambiguous. I understand why end use of panel software would be out of scope. However, configuring these panels does require sysadmin knowledge, and would otherwise be in scope.

The ambiguity is by design to some degree (or at least, so is my belief).  Web panels around here are almost as popular as spam and malware.

> I was surprised that an individual non moderator could place a question on hold that has been answered for over three years.

That would be a little surprising, but [users with a gold badge in a tag have binding close and reopen votes for the duplicate reason on questions originally tagged in that tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-close-vote-superpowers/254590#254590).

Users with a diamond next to their name *are* moderators.

> What's the process for disputing that status?

Well, you bring it up on meta, and/or flag it for reopening/moderator attention.  Given the popularity of administration panels in these parts, though, I wouldn't get my hopes up if I were you.

A related question I have for you is why you care - all its closure does is prevent people from adding new answers, and given that it has an accepted answer, I'm not sure how this would really impact you at all.  On the other hand, the existence of old, open questions about admin panels from back when they were considered topical is used as a justification for asking new questions, so closing old ones with a note that they're no longer topical does serve a useful purpose.

Comment: I care less about this question specifically, and more about how the moderation system works here. It's the first time I've seen that particular flag, and the system gives the user no information about how to dispute it. That's not a problem in this case, as you mention,  but it easily could be for new questions. In other words, I care for future reference.

Comment: @SeanW. Yeah, unfortunately, we don't have any ability to change the feedback mechanisms or the information presented to a user about the moderation system.  That would be a meta.stackexchange.com ting, since it's system-wide, and I suspect that this kind of thing has been asked for and declined (or put at the bottom of the list) more than once already - but feel free to check and/or point it out.